# The account is locked due to 3 failed logins - can I have this echoed in a terminal emulator?

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, sudo, login, password

Sometimes I get the password wrong, and it doesn't work anymore. Ok, fine, but `sudo` keeps saying the same thing, *Sorry, try again*, I since I forget about this from one episode to another, I got really confused. And I realize what the problem is when I try to log from another virtual console, where finally I get the clear message: *the account is locked due to 3 failed logins*.

Can I have this being echoed also in the terminal emulator in an X session, and not just in the virtual console?

Comment: What operating system are you using? The options you have depend on how the lockout mechanism is implemented. For instance, on systems that use [PAM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pam) you will likely be able to configure some module to display a custom message.

Comment: @fra-san, I don't know how I could skip that info. I'm on Arch.

Comment: I couldn't find a decent way, just a sort of workaround that I'm not posting as a proper answer: `alias sudo='[ "$(faillock --user "$(id -un)" | wc -l)" -gt 3 ] && echo "User faillocked" || sudo'` (where 3 is the number of failed attempts configured in `/etc/security/faillock.conf`).